# How to make simple url rewriting

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I'd like to know how to make a url rewriting?

Basically, if I go to `www.site.com/announce/123456` I'd like to actually use the page `www.site.com/annouce.php?id=123456`

I can't get any simple documentation about it.

Thanks

---

Based on **Gecko's answer** I made a .htaccess which works fine :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^announce/([0-9]+)$ announce.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use mod_rewrite into .htaccess file like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/announce/([0-9]+)$ announce.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

[QSA] flag allow you to pass other arguments in your url, like this :

```
www.site.com/announce/123456?arg2=test
```

Have fun :)